# Object.assign ie не поддерживает

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Как еще возможно объединить 2 объекта? Так чтобы ie поддерживал

Comment: Зачем вам понадобилось поддерживать ie в 2022 году?

Comment: Например [полифилом](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-object) из самой [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#see_also)

Comment: Например с помощью [jQuery.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Comment: Есть ещё у [lodash assign](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#assign)

Comment: У `lodash` есть ещё и [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge)

Answer (score 1):

Есть куча вариантов по типу использование полифилов или других каких-либо библиотек.
Вот лично мной написанная функция объединения объектов. В качестве параметров
она принимает неограниченное количество объектов, а возвращает объединение их.

Будьте внимательны ведь этот алгоритм не работает на Internet Explorer версии ниже 3.

```
function assign(){
    var res = {}
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
        for(var key in arguments[i]){
            res[key] = arguments[i][key]
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: Р - рекурсия. объединение объектов и замещение последним это несколько разные вещи

Comment: @teran , в каких случаях он будет не так работать?

Comment: в любых, где объекты имеют вложенные объекты, а ключи совпадают.

Comment: если уж `Object.assign` не поддерживается, то `for..of` и подавно не сработает

Comment: @teran, ну вообще сейчас поведение соответствует стандартному `Object.assign`

Comment: @Grundy а пардон. там чет накидали в комменты всяких extend, которые рекурсивно объединяют, я что-то нить и потерял

Comment: @teran, а мне казалось они тоже только поверхностно объединяли, разве нет?

Comment: @Grundy , вот всё проверил на поддержку кроме for of. Сейчас правлю)

Comment: @Grundy нет. Вернее не совсем нет. В случае jQuery, если просто вызывать для 2-х объектов, то будет поверхностное объединение, а если первым аргументом поставить `true`, тогда будет глубокое объединение. В случае с `lodash` у них есть [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge), который рекурсивен в отличи от [assign](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#assign), которым я поделился